# Inserir valores em um chart através de um button

Tags: c#, chart

Estou fazendo um gráfico através de um chart, que ao clicar em um button ele busca os dados e insere no chart. Porém toda vez que clico no button ele cria uma nova row (conforme a imagem abaixo). Como eu poderia estar fazendo para solucionar isso?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que sempre que fosse clicado no button o chart resetasse e mostrasse somente 1 row que seria a do aparelho selecionado na combobox

```
graficoEmpilhado.Series["Hipoglicemia"].Points.AddXY("", somH["TOTAL"].ToString());
graficoEmpilhado.Series["Dentro do alvo"].Points.AddXY("", somHiper["TOTAL"].ToString());
graficoEmpilhado.Series["Hiperglicemia"].Points.AddXY("", somAceitavel["TOTAL"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode atualizar assim:

```
graficoEmpilhado.Series["Hipoglicemia"].Points.ElementAt(0).SetValueY(somH["TOTAL"].ToString());
graficoEmpilhado.Series["Dentro do alvo"].Points.ElementAt(0).SetValueY(somHiper["TOTAL"].ToString());
graficoEmpilhado.Series["Hiperglicemia"].Points.ElementAt(0).SetValueY(somAceitavel["TOTAL"].ToString());
```

E atualizar o valor chamando

```
graficoEmpilhado.ResetAutoValues();
```

Comment: Ele da um erro

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção.

Sabe oque poderia ser?

Comment: Ele dá esse erro na primeira vez, quando vai gerar o chart?

Comment: Isso, ele da o erro na hora que chega no gráfico..

Comment: Se você não criou as séries no collection editor, precisa criar.  graficoEmpilhado.Series.Add("Hipoglicemia"), graficoEmpilhado.Series.Add("Dentro do alvo"), graficoEmpilhado.Series.Add("Hiperglicemia").

Comment: As 3 séries já estão criadas no collection editor (Hipoglicemia, Dentro do alvo e Hiperglicemia)...

Comment: Alguma parte do código deve estar limpando os Points